# How can I get 2 integer values from one input?

Tags: c++

I'm only in 10th grade and there is an exercise where I have to get an input like (input = 1/2) and this input needs to be stored in 2 different integers and I don't know how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Sorry if this question sounds dumb, but this is my first post here and I don't know the etiquette.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like `std::string s; std::cin >> s;` Check it matches what you expect (use `std::regex`), then parse at leisure.

Comment: Hey Daniel, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far and where'd it go wrong? Do you understand how to use `getline` and string streams? Is the format of your string always guaranteed to be `X/Y` where X and Y are both single digit integers? Do you care about parsing that `/` or do you just want to throw it away and store the ints?

Comment: Please be more specific about where you are stuck. How far did you get with a) making a HelloWorld run b) changing it to read something  and just output it as is c) changing it to read something like "1/2" d) changing to expect something like "1/2" and getting the "1" and the "2" separatly e) storing those two in different variables. Please show the code for what you already achieved an explain about what your specific problem is. Generally please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Since this seems to be about homework, please also study the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions The tour is about the general idea here, the how-to-ask is basically about the etiquette for asking. At least the tour was recommended to you when you created the account, wasn't it? Otherwise welcome to StackOverflow and allow me to express my respect for braving this community and people like me in only tenth grade. (no cynicism intended)

Comment: I haven't really tried anything, because I don't know how to even start with it. We haven't learned how to use getline, only with char(cin.getline(charname, size)). Yes, the format is always guaranteed, and yes they are both single digit intigers. I need to use the / because the input has to be a fraction. @scohe001

Comment: Sorry, but "I have not tried anything" is the wrong approach. Please follow the steps I outlined. Only that allows you to ask the kind of clear and specific question which is expected here.

Comment: I'd like to apologize, because as you pointed out this wasn't a good question. I got good answers and I could try to make something out of them. In the future I'll try to ask better questions and I'll try to be a good member of the community!

Comment: No need to apologise - but do that the site tour at some point. The C++ IO is obtuse - the accepted answer is perhaps the simplest way and it's especially good as it doesn't cut any corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the existing iostream functionality. There is nothing complicated about that. String parsing is not necessary. The inserter operator will skip whit spaces. Additionally, it will convert your given values into an integer variable. The slash will be read, checked and then discarded.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number1{}, number2{};
    char slash{};

    std::cout << "\nEnter a string: ";

    if (std::cin >> number1 >> slash >> number2 && slash == '/') {
        std::cout << "\n\nNumber 1: " << number1 << "\nNumber 2: " << number2 << "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\nError: invalid input\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know in many ways it's a question of style (and some software houses insist on it), but you don't need to initialise the automatic variables on this occasion.

Comment: All variables must always be initialized. For me, there cannot be a discussion about that. Any professinal software developer should do it. If you drive a car with a break by wire software, would you accept none initalized variables? Really nobody would and no assessment could be passed . . .

Comment: ...although that said I'm buying a German car next year so perhaps it is reassuring. Personally though I like to keep variables uninitialised and I have runtime checks enabled for any path that reads an uninitialised variable. In my field (finance maths - you know the bastion of wooly programmers) that gives you some reassurance your code is behaving.

Answer (score 3):

Read two integers and ignore/match the character between them. The nicest way to match the character would be a manipulator:

```
std::istream& slash(std::istream& in) {
    if ((in >> std::ws).peek() == '/') {
        in.ignore();
    }
    else {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    int numerator, denominator;
    if (std::cin >> numerator >> slash >> denominator) {
        std::cout << " read " << numerator << '/' << denominator << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: A little bit complicated for such a simple task . . .

Comment: Absolutely not - IO is one of those things that grows in complexity as a project evolves. This is not overdesigned by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @ArminMontigny: yes, it would be nice to have a standard library manipulator to check/skipa given character. Once you assume the manipulator `slash` is given I think that's not too bad, though. That is one of the things from `scanf()` IOStreams don't cover: `scanf("%d/%d\n", &numerator, &denominator)` (I still do *not* recommend using `scanf()`, though).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Take the input as a `std::string` and then parse it.

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

std::pair<int,int> inputNumbers()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Input: ";
    std::cin >> input;
    size_t slashPos = input.find('/');
    if(slashPos == input.npos || slashPos == 0 || slashPos == input.size() - 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! Please try again.\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    std::pair<int,int> ret;
    try
    {
        ret.first = std::stoi(input.substr(0,slashPos));
        ret.second = std::stoi(input.substr(slashPos+1,input.size()-slashPos-1));
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument&)
    {
        std::cout << "Error! Please try again.\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::pair<int,int> inputs = inputNumbers();
    std::cout << "First number: " << inputs.first << ". Second number: " << inputs.second << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: @Bathsheba: Your favourite does not compile. It throws with testcase "5/" and "a/b". It is too complicated for this purpose

Comment: @ArminMontigny: Oops, in which case you could consider downvoting the answer. It's only my favourite insofar that the `std::string` is read from the input. I didn't really check the rest, to be honest.

Comment: (Made a trivial edit and rolled back so I can retract my upvote. Silly Stack Overflow with it's "you can't change your mind" rules.)